# Looping 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to see if there is a way I can loop through these arrays and see which one matches with the array that has {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1}
The set of arrays are provided in the main function. An update to a question...if it matches the correct code it has to print "100% accurate"...if it does not it has to print the accuracy in terms of percentage.

```
public static void compare(int[][] security_codes){
        for (int i=0; i<security_codes.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<security_codes[i].length; j++)
            {
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[][] security_codes = {{0,1,1,7,7,2,2,5,0,3},
{5,1,4,0,5,0,9,8,7,5}, {9,8,3,4,0,9,6,7,7,1},
 {5,9,5,7,1,4,9,7,6,9}, {7,1,1,4,6,7,9,1,1,0},
{6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1}, {6,1,1,8,4,9,7,0,1,2},
 {9,5,4,6,3,1,4,7,2,9}};
        
        compare(security_codes);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you store the security codes as an array? Can't you use a string for that which would be much much easier

Comment: Too short for an answer: Just use [Arrays.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arrays.equals() method to compare two arrays.

```
public static void compare(int[][] security_codes,int[] security_code){
  for (int i=0; i<security_codes.length; i++)
    {
     if (Arrays.equals(security_code,security_codes[i]))
        System.out.println("Key Matched");  
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] security_code = {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1};
        int[][] security_codes = {{0,1,1,7,7,2,2,5,0,3},
        {5,1,4,0,5,0,9,8,7,5}, {9,8,3,4,0,9,6,7,7,1},
        {5,9,5,7,1,4,9,7,6,9}, {7,1,1,4,6,7,9,1,1,0},
        {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1}, {6,1,1,8,4,9,7,0,1,2},
        {9,5,4,6,3,1,4,7,2,9}};
        
        compare(security_codes,security_code);
    }
```